# Android bundle value always reading 0

Tags: android, android-intent

In my android app, I store a value 1 in a bundle, and then start the activity, then I read the bundle value from the new activity, and its 0. I'm not sure what's going wrong...

```
    content.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, ThreadScreen.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("thread_id", Integer.toString(thread.getId(), 10));
            context.startActivity(myIntent);

            Transition.TransitionForward(context);
        }
    });
```

the myIntent mExtras = `Bundle[{thread_id=1}]`.

This code, puts a value 1 with key `thread_id`. Then I start the activity, and then I read it here

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_thread_screen);

    // activates the action bar
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    int thread_id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("thread_id");
    setUpScreen(thread_id);

    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
}
```

Here `thread_id` has a value of 0. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing a String key and reading an int. To write and read the same key, you need to use putExtra(String, int) and getInt.

Answer (score 0):

1. getIntent().getExtras() will give you bundle
2. In your case you have put String type value in Intent Extra
3. So to get the value in ThreadClass Activity do below

   ```
   int thread_id = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("thread_id"));
   ```

Hope this helps